# Получаю пустой документ из beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

пытаюсь настроить парсер, чтобы данные с нескольких сайтов были в одном csv файле, но файл на выходе пустой, как мне это можно поправить?

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Zara Women's Sale
zara_women_sale_url = 'https://www.zara.com/jp/ja/woman-sales-selection-l6346.html?v1=2305666'
zara_women_sale_response = requests.get(zara_women_sale_url)
zara_women_sale_soup = BeautifulSoup(zara_women_sale_response.content, 'html.parser')

# Zara Men's New In (Page 2)
zara_men_new_in_url = 'https://www.zara.com/jp/ja/man-new-in-l711.html?v1=2297655&page=2'
zara_men_new_in_response = requests.get(zara_men_new_in_url)
zara_men_new_in_soup = BeautifulSoup(zara_men_new_in_response.content, 'html.parser')

# Uniqlo Women's Ranking
uniqlo_women_url = 'https://www.uniqlo.com/jp/ja/spl/ranking/women'
uniqlo_women_response = requests.get(uniqlo_women_url)
uniqlo_women_soup = BeautifulSoup(uniqlo_women_response.content, 'html.parser')

# Uniqlo Men's Ranking
uniqlo_men_url = 'https://www.uniqlo.com/jp/ja/spl/ranking/men'
uniqlo_men_response = requests.get(uniqlo_men_url)
uniqlo_men_soup = BeautifulSoup(uniqlo_men_response.content, 'html.parser')

# Gap Coordinate
gap_coordinate_url = 'https://www.gap.co.jp/gap/featured/link-coordinate-3016691'
gap_coordinate_response = requests.get(gap_coordinate_url)
gap_coordinate_soup = BeautifulSoup(gap_coordinate_response.content, 'html.parser')

# H&M Women's View All
hm_women_url = 'https://www2.hm.com/ja_jp/ladies/shop-by-product/view-all.html'
hm_women_response = requests.get(hm_women_url)
hm_women_soup = BeautifulSoup(hm_women_response.content, 'html.parser')

# H&M Men's New Arrivals View All
hm_men_url = 'https://www2.hm.com/ja_jp/men/new-arrivals/view-all.html'
hm_men_response = requests.get(hm_men_url)
hm_men_soup = BeautifulSoup(hm_men_response.content, 'html.parser')

# Create a list to store the scraped data
data = []

# Scrape Zara Women's Sale
zara_women_sale_items = zara_women_sale_soup.find_all('article', class_='product')
for item in zara_women_sale_items:
    title_element = item.find('a', class_='name')
    title = title_element.text.strip() if title_element else ''
    price_element = item.find('span', class_='price__integer')
    price = price_element.text.strip() if price_element else ''
    data.append(['Zara Women Sale', title, price])

# Scrape Zara Men's New In (Page 2)
zara_men_new_in_items = zara_men_new_in_soup.find_all('article', class_='product')
for item in zara_men_new_in_items:
    title_element = item.find('a', class_='name')
    title = title_element.text.strip() if title_element else ''
    price_element = item.find('span', class_='price__integer')
    price = price_element.text.strip() if price_element else ''
    data.append(['Zara Men New In', title, price])

# Scrape Uniqlo Women's Ranking
uniqlo_women_items = uniqlo_women_soup.find_all('div', class_='c-productListItem')
for item in uniqlo_women_items:
    title_element = item.find('p', class_='c-productListItem_link')
    title = title_element.text.strip() if title_element else ''
    price_element = item.find('span', class_='c-productListItem_priceValue')
    price = price_element.text.strip() if price_element else ''
    data.append(['Uniqlo Women Ranking', title, price])

# Scrape Uniqlo Men's Ranking
uniqlo_men_items = uniqlo_men_soup.find_all('div', class_='c-productListItem')
for item in uniqlo_men_items:
    title_element = item.find('p', class_='c-productListItem_link')
    title = title_element.text.strip() if title_element else ''
    price_element = item.find('span', class_='c-productListItem_priceValue')
    price = price_element.text.strip() if price_element else ''
    data.append(['Uniqlo Men Ranking', title, price])

# Scrape Gap Coordinate
gap_coordinate_items = gap_coordinate_soup.find_all('div', class_='c-productListItem')
for item in gap_coordinate_items:
    title_element = item.find('a', class_='c-productListItem_link')
    title = title_element.text.strip() if title_element else ''
    price_element = item.find('span', class_='c-productListItem_priceValue')
    price = price_element.text.strip() if price_element else ''
    data.append(['Gap Coordinate', title, price])

# Scrape H&M Women's View All
hm_women_items = hm_women_soup.find_all('div', class_='product-item')
for item in hm_women_items:
    title_element = item.find('a', class_='link')
    title = title_element.text.strip() if title_element else ''
    price_element = item.find('span', class_='price')
    price = price_element.text.strip() if price_element else ''
    data.append(['H&M Women View All', title, price])

# Scrape H&M Men's New Arrivals View All
hm_men_items = hm_men_soup.find_all('div', class_='product-item')
for item in hm_men_items:
    title_element = item.find('a', class_='link')
    title = title_element.text.strip() if title_element else ''
    price_element = item.find('span', class_='price')
    price = price_element.text.strip() if price_element else ''
    data.append(['H&M Men New Arrivals', title, price])

# Export the data to a CSV file
with open('scraped_data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['Category', 'Title', 'Price'])  # Write header row
    writer.writerows(data)  # Write data rows

print('Data exported to scraped_data.csv successfully.')
```